# How to decode string to use with Google Language Detection API?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urldecode

I want to use [Google Language Detection API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/#Detect) in my app to detect language of url parameter. For example user requests url

> http://myapp.com/q?Это тест

and gets message "Russian". I do it this way:

```
def get(self):                                            
        url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/detect?v=1.0&q="+self.request.query                        
        try:
            data = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())                
            self.response.out.write('<html><body>' + data["responseData"]["language"] +'</body></html>')                                  
        except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
            self.response.out.write( "HTTP error: %d" % e.code )
        except urllib2.URLError, e:
            self.response.out.write( "Network error: %s" % e.reason.args[1])
```

but always get "English" as result because url is encoded in

> http://myapp.com/q?%DD%F2%EE%20%F2%E5%F1%F2

I've tried  `urllib.quote , urllib.urlencode` with no luck.

**How I have to decode this url for Google Api?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `urllib.unquote` is what you are looking for:

```
>>> from urllib import unquote
>>> unquote("%DD%F2%EE%20%F2%E5%F1%F2")
```

This gives you a string in which the characters are in whatever encoding that you've used in the URL. If you want to recode it to a different encoding (say, UTF-8), you have to create a `unicode` object first and then use the `encode` method of the `unicode` object to recode it:

```
>>> from urllib import unquote, quote
>>> import json, urllib2, pprint
>>> decoded = unicode(unquote("%DD%F2%EE%20%F2%E5%F1%F2"), "windows-1251")
>>> print decoded
Это тест
>>> recoded = decoded.encode("utf-8")
```

At this point, we have an UTF-8 encoded string, but this is still not suitable to be passed on to the Google Language Detection API:

```
>>> recoded
'\xd0\xad\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe \xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd1\x82'
```

Since you want to include this string in a URL as a query argument, you have to encode it using `urllib.quote`:

```
>>> url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/detect?v=1.0&q=%s" % quote(recoded)
>>> data = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
>>> pprint.pprint(data)
{u'responseData': {u'confidence': 0.094033934,
                   u'isReliable': False,
                   u'language': u'ru'},
 u'responseDetails': None,
 u'responseStatus': 200}
```

Comment: Looks good when I try to print it, but when I send it to Google it   throws exception: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position

Comment: You have to pass `recoded` on to `urllib.quote` to obtain a representation which can safely be appended to the Google Language API URL. I'm modifying my example to show that.